# How to set up HTML meta viewport to start 100% width?

Tags: android, ios, css, html

I want to show my website on mobile devices in 100% width landscape and portrait view too.

I was tried this HTML code without any CSS declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 1000px; background:#ff0">hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in landscape view, but if I start in portrait... so I doesn't work good. It is zoomed in like landscape view.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the webpage to always fit entirely on the screen? So if portrait mode is less than 1000px like 500px it should zoom out until the webpage fits within that 500px?

Comment: @TreeTree : yep, I think I want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded your HTML in a basic WebView and it looks fine to me.  Maybe it's an issue with your layout and not with the HTML?

Here is the (very basic) WebView I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

And here is the onCreate that I used to test your code:

```
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    String data = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"hu\"> <head>     <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">     <title>test page</title> </head> <body>     <div style=\"width: 1000px; background:#ff0\">hello world</div> </body> </html>";
    webView.loadData(data, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment to my comment:

I'm 99% sure the behavior you want is already the default behavior. When you set the `width=device-width` part of the viewport it will cause the device to behave similar to you simply resizing the browser window on the desktop.

If you remove that part from the `content` attribute it should behave the way you want.

Comment: I tried what you suggest, but does not solved the problem. The page showed still landscape width in portrait view too.

Comment: Perhaps you can try setting it to `width=NNN` where `NNN` is the width of your page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm at a loss then. This is the behavior that I usually try to counteract on mobile devices.